# Cleaning up data scraped from website and constructing clean Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, normalization, data-cleaning

I am practicing my web scraping and am having a tough time cleaning data and putting it into a DataFrame to later manipulate. My code is something like:

```html
import requests as re
import urllib.request as ure
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

myURL = "http://naturalstattrick.com/games.php"
reURL = re.get(myURL)
mySoup = soup(reURL.content, 'html.parser')
print(mySoup)
```

From that, I want to isolate the date, teams, and score - which always begins with < b >, followed by spacehyphenspace, followed by the away team (which can be 1 of 31 teams), space, awayTeamScore, commaspace, homeTeam, space, homeTeamScore, and ends with < /b >.

Then I want to isolate all of the numeric data that starts with < td > and ends with < /td > into their own columns but obviously alongside the record of the game.

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: `gameInfo = []
for b in mySoup.find_all('b'):
    gameInfo.append(b)`

Not a lot of more advanced cleaning because I'm having trouble understanding how to isolate a lot of the scraped information. I also just saw that the data I want to isolate is all between < tr > and < /tr > but I'm still struggling on an efficient way to identify the pertinent information and place it into it's own column.